# Cannot get value from Textbox using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, web-testing, getattribute

I am unable to get the data from the textbox using Selenium WebDriver.
Here how the textbox element code looks like

```
<input aria-invalid="false" disabled="" id="2033323" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input
MuiOutlinedInput-input Mui-disabled Mui-disabled" value="104" style="padding: 5px 7px;">
```

I see "104" in the textbox on UI and in my test I need to check, that this value is displayed.
The id is unique, so I tried both By.xpath("//*[@id='2033323']") and By.id("2033323") to create the locator.

I can get values from e.g. "type" attribute via

```
driver.findElement(By.id("2033323")).getAttribute("type"));
```

But I get empty result if I try to get value from "value" attribute via

```
driver.findElement(By.id("2033323")).getAttribute("value"));
or
driver.findElement(By.id("2033323")).getCssValue("value"));
```

and .getText() is not suitable as there is no simple text there .

I even tried

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String temperature = (String)(jsExecutor.executeScript("return document.getElementById('2033323').value"));
```

and get an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

Wait until the element is found and find the element using xpath and get the value

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='2033323']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='2033323']").getAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: the problem is not the waiter, even in Debug I do not get the value

Comment: What error does the getText() throw?

Comment: Sorry, I formulated it incorrectly. No error, just an empty result, cause there is no simple text in tag, the value is contained only in the tag <input disabled id="2033323" .... value="some_value">